# Springboot login from different url

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to implement Springboot Security for my first project and I don't know how to do the next thing:

- I have the frontend and backend in different folders
- on the frontend I use live-server with the url http://127.0.0.1:9000/ and the backend with the url http://localhost:8080
- my login page is http://127.0.0.1:9000/login.html

Can anyone help me binding the frontend login page with the backend ?

My HTML:

```
 <body>
      <div class="login-container">
           <div class="login-box">
                <h1 class="login-header">LOGIN</h1>
                <div class="login-input-container">
                    <form action="http://localhost:8080/login" method="POST">

                        <div class="login-input-container-email-wrapper">

                            <input type="text" class="login-input-email" placeholder="Email" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" required/>
                            <svg class="login-input-email-icon">
                                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-mail_outline"></use>
                            </svg>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="login-input-container-password-wrapper">
                            <input type="password" class="login-input-password" placeholder="Password" required/>
                            <svg class="login-input-password-icon">
                                <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-vpn_key"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="login-submit">
                            <button class="login-submit-button login-submit-button--green">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <span class="login-separator">Or Login With</span>
                    <div class="login-google">
                        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" id="my-signin2"
                        style="display:flex;justify-content:stretch;align-items: stretch;width: 500;" data-longtitle="true"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

MY Springboot security config:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("http://127.0.0.1:9000/login.html").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("http://127.0.0.1:9000")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a login controller with a rest end point where you verify credentials and you need to map that in `configure()` method. Not the front-end url. From front-end you should call that rest end point. Modify the configure() as below.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("http://127.0.0.1:9000")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

And the login controller should be like

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login"", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUserByDetails(@RequestBody Map<String, String> credentials, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
          // business logic
    }
}
```

You can refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login-angular for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Do refer below config and modify your config file as required!

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login") // Specifies the login page URL (goes to controller to look for this URL)
        //.loginProcessingUrl("/login") // Specifies the URL,which is used in action on the <from> tag
        //.successHandler(successHandler)
        .defaultSuccessUrl("http://127.0.0.1:9000")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout");

        // Following is to go to direct controller URL for access denied.
        // exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");

}
```

Here, you must understand the difference between `loginPage()` and `loginProcessingUrl()`.

Now your controller should have mapping for `/login`

So, your controller will have method to call your `custom-login-page` with below config

```
@GetMapping("/login")
    public String customLoginPage() {
    return "custom-login-page";
}
```